# Proof that Muckenhoupt's $A_q$ Condition Implies $A_p$ for $p<q$?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, harmonic-analysis, approximation-theory

It is said $f\in A_p$ if it satisfies the following (Muckenhoupt's $A_p$) condition:
$$\underset{I\subset\mathbb{R}}\sup\left(\dfrac{1}{|I|}\int_If(t)dt\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{|I|}\int_If(t)^{-\frac{p'}{p}}\right)^\frac{p}{p'}<\infty$$
where the $\sup$ is taken over bounded intervals $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and $p'$ is the Holder conjugate of $p$.

I find the following fact that $A_1\subset A_p\subset A_\infty$ for $1\leq p\leq\infty$ on Wikipedia's page, but have not found this proven in any papers so far (nor have found a proof myself).

Any reference to this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your title asks about $p<q$, but your question asks about $A_1$. Which inclusion are you asking about. (If both, could you edit the other one into your question? The one in the title is just Hölder's inequality, by the way...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any nonnegative measurable function $h$ on a probability space $\Omega$ the quasi-norm $\|h\|_q=\left(\int_{\Omega} h^q\right)^{1/q}$ is increasing with $q$, $0<q<\infty$. Indeed, Jensen's inequality gives 
$$ \left(\int_{\Omega} h\right)^q \le \int_{\Omega} h^q \tag1 $$
which says $\|h\|_1\le \|h\|_q$ for $q\ge 1$. Given $0< q_1<q_2<\infty$, apply (1) to $h^{q_1}$ with $q=q_2/q_1$.

Specialize the above to $\Omega$ being an interval $I$ with normalized Lebesgue measure, and $h=1/f$. Then 
$$ \left(\dfrac{1}{|I|}\int_If(t)^{-\frac{p'}{p}}\right)^\frac{p}{p'} = \|h\|_q \tag2$$
where $q=p'/p$ is a decreasing function of $p$. Therefore, (2) is a decreasing  function of $p$, which implies that the inequality
$$\underset{I\subset\mathbb{R}}\sup\left(\dfrac{1}{|I|}\int_If(t)dt\right)\left(\dfrac{1}{|I|}\int_If(t)^{-\frac{p'}{p}}\right)^\frac{p}{p'}<\infty$$
becomes weaker (more permissive) as $p$ increases.

To handle $A_\infty$, one can introduce $\|h\|_0=\exp\int_\Omega \log h$ and argue that $\|h\|_0\le \|h\|_q$ for all $q>0$; the rest goes as above.

A reference is *Harmonic Analysis* by Stein, section V.1.3, page 195:

[image: screengrab]